# How to really reset a unit test?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, reset

I'd like to test class and gem loading. Have a look at the following stupid test case:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'shoulda'

class SimpleTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

    context 'This test' do

       should 'first load something' do
           require 'bundler'

           assert Object.const_defined? :Bundler
       end

       should 'second have it reset again' do
           assert !Object.const_defined?(:Bundler)
       end

       teardown do
         # This works, but is tedious and unclean
         #Object.send :remove_const, :Bundler rescue nil

         # Instead I want something like this ;)
         magic_reset
       end

    end

end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the code is meant to indicate what `magic_reset` would do, or if it's meant to indicate why you want `magic_reset`, but you are aware that if  `'second have it reset again'` were run by itself, or was run prior to `first load something`, it'd be a pretty useless test, right?

Comment: @Andrew: Of course the second test would be "useless", but it would not fail. `magic_reset` should somehow reset the required gems / loaded files, so each of the tests starts with the same environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about creating a subclass of `Test::Unit::TestCase` which runs the test method in a forked process?

```
class ForkingTestCase < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def run(...)
    fork do
      super.run(...)

      # somehow communicate the result back to the parent process
      # this is the hard part
    end
  end  
end
```

If this can be implemented, it should then just be a matter of changing the base class of your test case.

Comment: I already thought about forking a process, but never thought about subclassing `TestCase`. I think this seems to be worth a try.

Comment: Well, it really works. I got it working for both 1.8.7 (`Test::Unit`) and 1.9.2 (`MiniTest::Unit`).

The problem is, you'd also have to isolate single test cases, which in fact means you also have to subclass `TestSuite`. I think this is a bigger task, maybe worth an own gem. ;)

Comment: @Koraktor: Nice! It could indeed be useful as a gem to use while testing code that rely on reopening classes or have other effects on the environment that are difficult to isolate.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you cannot unload a file that you have loaded. You need to start a separate Ruby process for every test. (Or a separate Ruby instance if you are running on a Ruby implementation which supports multiple instances in the same process.)

Comment: Would I still be able to have an overview about passed / failed tests? As far as I can tell, this seems like overkill - much like the `#remove_const` way.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Kernel#load](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-load) with `wrap` set to true:

> load(filename, wrap=false) → true
>
> Loads and executes the Ruby program in the file filename. If the
>   filename does not resolve to an absolute path, the file is searched
>   for in the library directories listed in $:. If the optional wrap
>   parameter is true, the loaded script will be executed under an
>   anonymous module, protecting the calling program’s global namespace.
>   In no circumstance will any local variables in the loaded file be
>   propagated to the loading environment.

each time you want to do a test of bundler, `load` it into a new anonymous module, do your tests on the bundler class within that module, and then go onto your next test.

If your code refers to the `Bundler` constant, then you'd have to set and unset that constant, though.

I haven't tried it myself, but can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: This is really interesting, although I don't think this is applicable in such a case. For example, `load` must now the file system location of the loaded file and that's not practicable for gems. Additionally, it seems that loading with `wrap` will not propagate any code into the calling code, i.e. you won't be able to use classes etc. defined there.

Answer (score -1):

Try keeping track of what constants were defined before your tests started, and what constants are defined after your test finished, and remove the constants that were defined during the test.

I guess this isn't so much telling you how to call magic_reset as how to implement magic_reset.

Comment: I already thought about something like that. I'm still searching for a smart way to do this, though.